# set LOG_ENABLED=FALSE on scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have trying to disable Scrapy debugging print, after a quick search online i found out that this is the code lines that help other people:

```
LOG_ENABLED = False
```

or

```
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
```

in both cases it didn't solve my problem.

I appreciate if anybody can help me.

Comment: What behavior are you getting exactly -- can you share an example log? Also, where exactly are you putting the log settings, is it in settings.py? What Scrapy version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just getting the usual log from Scrapy and yes I’m using settings.py and for other features it's working fine. 
I found out a solution for this problem.
I don't know the reason why it didn't work "physically" on settings.py but when this is what fix my problem:

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
settings.set('LOG_ENABLED', False ,priority='cmdline')
```

I just put it in the spider class and every time the spider run the setting is "dynamically" changed

tnx for your replay :)